# Change notification light blink frequency in android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, notification-led

Whenever a message or call comes and is unseen, notification led blinks but with lesser frequency. I'm missing it frequently.

I want the notification light to blink at a more frequency, or be continuously lit. Is that possible?

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Comment: Yes. Using CyanogenMod-12-SNAPSHOT-YNG4NA0256-tomato (android-5.0) stable.

Comment: There may be an option Notification light under Settings -> Display & Lights. Enable Use custom values and configure the Missed call lights. Could it be that you already tried this?

Comment: Under `Settings --> Display & lights --> Lights` there is an option for `Battery light` with toggles on/off and pulse when battery low. But there isn't any option for `Notification light` or similar. Maybe that is device specific?

Comment: I think so. Can you check and verify whether there is any key containing the string `notification_light_pulse` in the table `system` or any other table of `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` database?

Comment: I'm very new to sqlite commands, so I exported the database to sql and searched normally. Yes, the string is present in system table. The matching line in sql is `insert into system values (23, 'notification_light_pulse', '1');`

Comment: There's always an app for that :P you can try checking out [**Light Manager on the Google Play Store**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koo.lightmanager&hl=en). Worked without any problems for me